# How to redirect new connections on connectify/m-hotspot to a WAMP page?

Tags: php, wamp, http-redirect, hotspot

I am using WAMP to run a local LAN service. I also share my ethernet network using m-hotspot with anyone who connects via wifi.

What I want is that whenever someone connects to the hotspot, he/she should be redirected to the login page that I made in www folder of the WAMP directory.

Does m-hotspot or connectify has this feature ?
If not, what are some other hotspot software that do ?
Or should I use the CMD method to make hotspot (the "`netsh wlan hostenetwork`" thing) and make some tweaks in network settings in control panel?